# How to fix constraint error: "Invoice number must be unique per company" when validating a vendor bill in Odoo 10?

Tags: validation, odoo, constraints, odoo-10

I'm getting this error when I click on Validate button on "Vendor Bill" form:
[Constraint error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9kXs.png)

I know for sure that the invoice number is unique. I even tried to create a completely new vendor bill with different vendor and I still get the same error.

It used to be fine, but for some reason it's throwing an error now. I want to try to restore my db before it started happening, but I'm not sure it'll help.

Any thoughts on why it's happening and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Hi this has nothing to do with programming. You should try to ask about such behaviour in the [Odoo Help Forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum).

Answer (score 1):

I agree your question is not related to programming. But nonetheless, this is probably caused by the fact that you have demo data on your database. Demo data will create validated invoices with valid numbers while the sequence number is still at one. At some point the values will overlap.

Just create a database without demo values and you should get rid of your problem.

Comment: It's not a programming question, sorry about that. I posted it on Odoo forum, but still didn't get any answer.
Anyway thanks for advise. DB was created without demo values originally. So I restored my db and it works for now, no errors. But I think it's a temporary solution.